# C# MVC repository inheritance and common dataContext

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, inheritance, repository, datacontext

Say I have a GenericRepository:

```
public class IGenericRepository 
{
     // bla bla bla
}

public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository
{
     public myDataContext dc = new myDataContext(); 

     // bla bla bla
}
```

and I have a specific repository for categories:

```
public class CategoryRepository : GenericRepository
{
     // bla bla bla
}
```

and in my controller:

```
public ActionResult something() 
{
     CategoryRepository cr = new CategoryRepository();
     GenericRepository gr = new GenericRepository();
     Category cat = cr.GetMostUsedCategory();
     SubCategory sub = gr.GetById(15); 

     // And after I make some changes on these two entities I have to:

     cr.Save();
     gr.Save();
}
```

Now, is it possible to use a common datacontext that applies to all repositories? So that when I save from `gr.Save()` it will apply for `cr`? I mean:

```
//Instead of  
cr.Save();
gr.Save();

//I want
gr.Save(); // And my category will also be saved.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this? (pass your derived repository to the generic)

```
public class IGenericRepository 
{
   void Save();
}

public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository
{     
    public myDataContext dc = new myDataContext(); 
    private _IGenericRepository = null;

   // bla bla bla

    public GenericRepository(IGenericRepository repository)
    {
        _IGenericRepository = repository;
    }

    void Save()
    {
       _IGenericRepository.Save();
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IGenericRepository contains your save method?

```
public class IGenericRepository 
{
     save{};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case here given that CategoryRepository inherits from GenericRepository why not just use the CategoryRepository for both calls and therfore the same context.  However the best approach is to inject your context through a DI container and use the LifetimeManager of your container to ensure the same context is available for the entire HttpRequest.

If you happen to be using Microsoft's Unity, I wrote a blog post about it [here](http://frozenorange.wordpress.com/2010/07/15/lifetime-of-an-entity-framework-context/)

Comment: well, you're right, for this example I can do it but there are cases which I have to use different specific repositories so what should I do there?

Comment: If the same context is injected into both repositories calling Save on either will cause the desired behaviour.  However, this pattern (Unit of Work) is made a little more explicit by abstracting the context via an interface.  Your controller will then also take a dependency on this interface and make the decision on when to call Save.  Since this interface resolves to the context passed into both repositories you will achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Unit Of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern for these purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more layer of abstraction for the DataContext concept:

```
//It is the generic datacontext
public interface IDataContext
{
    void Save();
}

//It is an implementation of the datacontext. You will
//have one of this class per datacontext
public class MyDataContext:IDataContext
{
    private DataContext _datacontext;
    public MyDataContext(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        _datacontext = dataContext;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _datacontext.Save();
    }
}
```

Then in your repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TDataContext> : IGenericRepository where TDataContext: IDataContext,new()
{
    public TDataContext dc = new TDataContext();

    // bla bla bla
}

public class CategoryRepository:GenericRepository<MyDataContext>
{
    // bla bla bla
    public void SaveSomething()
    {
        dc.Save();
    }
}
```

Of course, it is just a way to go :-) You can improve it, but the point is abstract the concept of the Datacontext. You can use your code for any datacontext (even [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate)).